# PIVOT table in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Can you help me to pivot the details in my Oracle table **PAY_DETAILS**

```
PAY_NO                                    NOT NULL NUMBER
EMP_NO                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
EMP_ERN_DDCT_NO                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(21)
ERN_DDCT_CATNO                            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
ERN_DDCT_CATNAME                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1000)
PAY_MONTH                                 NOT NULL DATE
AMOUNT                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(10,2)
EARN_DEDUCT                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)

 select EMP_NO,EMP_ERN_DDCT_NO,AMOUNT,EARN_DEDUCT, ERN_DDCT_CATNO from   pay_details 

EMP_NO     EMP_ERN_DDCT_NO           AMOUNT EA ERN_DDCT_C
---------- --------------------- ---------- -- ----------
219        10                           175 A  001
219        1                           5000 A  002
794        7                          50000 A  001
769        6                          35000 A  001
465        4                           5000 A  002
289        2                           5000 A  002
435        3                           5000 A  002
816        38                             5 D  201
737        30                             5 D  201
```

Is it possible to make this output into a cross tab?

Comment: Not without a lot more information. Such as sample data and what you actually want the data to look like once it's been pivoted. And the queries that you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

So, lets assume you want to pivot your salary data for each month. You can use the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT emp_no, 
         emp_ern_ddct_no, 
         pay_month, 
         amount
  FROM   pay_details
)
PIVOT
(
  SUM(amount)
  FOR pay_month IN ('01/01/2016', '02/01/2016', '03/01/2016','04/01/2016','05/01/2016','06/01/2016','07/01/2016','08/01/2016','09/01/2016','10/01/2016','11/01/2016','12/01/2016')
)
ORDER BY emp_no;
```

This is just an example, you can PIVOT your data based on different columns. For more details refer to the following link.

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php

http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506

Since you are on Oracle 10g PIVOT wont work. Try using something similar to the below query.

```
SELECT emp_no,
  SUM(CASE WHEN pay_month ='01/01/2016' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) jan_pay,
  SUM(CASE WHEN pay_month ='02/01/2016' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) feb_pay,
  SUM(CASE WHEN pay_month ='03/01/2016' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) march_pay
  .........
FROM pay_details
GROUP BY emp_no;
```

Comment: Great.But just now I found oracle 10 g does not support PIVOT..Any idea to do this with CASE

Comment: Edited my answer and added solution using case statement.

Comment: Lot of apples for you.
One more thing ... How to include Pay Category (ERN_DDCT_CATNAME)
as well into this.So it will grouped by
 1)Pay Month 2)ERN_DDCT_CATNAME
Since I have dynamic number of ERN_DDCT_CATNAME s per each employee how to handle it?

Comment: For that you can refine your case statement   sum(case when pay_month ='01/01/2016' and ERN_DDCT_CATNAME = '001' then AMOUNT else 0 end) jan_001_pay, sum(case when pay_month ='01/01/2016' and ERN_DDCT_CATNAME = '002' then AMOUNT else 0 end) jan_002_pay,

Comment: Of coz. Is there any way to put the Pay Category (ERN_DDCT_CATNAME) dynamically into the query?

Comment: No, I don't think you can do it dynamically using SQL.